# Force scrolling on textarea background image?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have an editable textarea displaying code text, and I want to apply some simple styling with a background pattern simulating the typical `<pre>` styling.

When I place the background image and scroll within the textarea, the background image is fixed to the textarea and the text flows on top when scrolling.

**I want the background image to scroll together with the text.**

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trollsyn/9yYMG/)**

The only bulletproof solution I've come across while searching is something like [this](http://codemirror.net/), but I was hoping to find a simple CSS solution to this.

Comment: As far as I know there's no way to do this with CSS I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, thank you nevertheless for confirming my dark suspicions!